# Nano Editor: Delete to the end of the file

Tags: nano

When using [GNU's Nano Editor](http://www.nano-editor.org/), is it possible to delete from the actual cursor position **to the end** of the text file?

My **workaround** for now: keep pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (the *delete full line* hotkey). But this method is not so confortable on slow remote connections (telnet, SSH... etc).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to [Nano Keyboard Commands](http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/sedwards/Nano/NanoKeyboardCommands.html), you can do this with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>:

```
M-T    Cut from the cursor position to the end of the file
```

where the `M` is "alt" (referring to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key).  In the documentation, "cut" is another way of saying delete or remove, e.g.,

```
^K     Cut the current line and store it in the cutbuffer
```

Comment: A perfect solution. To note: the two keys must be pressed consecutively, not at the same time. And the cut is not sent to the Windows's clipboard when SSHing with Putty, so it is just a method to delete, not paste, but the question was not requesting for copy-pasting.